# How to interact with a fragment's views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that gets some fragments and puts them in a list.
One of the fragments has a TextView whose font I'd like to change.

From within the fragment class I cannot do that, because its not an activity and interacting with TextViews there is unavailable.

From within the activity that contains the fragment list, I dont know how to reach that textview, so I can work with it.

here is some code:

```
public class MyProfileFriendsFriendFragmentList extends SherlockListFragment {
    private TextView tvMyFriendsListFriendName;
    private Typeface font1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Daddy Yankee", "Michael Schumacher", "Krista Rock", "Ben Jordan", "Bruce Springsteen", "Jane Carol", "Susan Jackson", "Marshall Mathers", "Cauth Bodva", "Ringo Starr" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_profile_friend_fragment, R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        tvMyFriendsListFriendName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName);


        try {
            font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(), Configurationz.Fontz.FONT_1);
            tvMyFriendsListFriendName.setTypeface(font1); //this doesnt work.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data

    }
}
```

This doesnt work. I dont know why. The exception stacktrace says there is a nullpointer exception when I try to interact with the TextView.

This is a screenshot of what LogCat says. Right Click on it and View Image for full size view
[image]

EDIT: After following the advice I got, here is what I changed my code to:

```
public class MyProfileFriendsFriendFragmentList extends SherlockListFragment {
    private Typeface font1;

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Daddy Yankee", "Michael Schumacher", "Krista Rock",
            "Ben Jordan", "Bruce Springsteen", "Jane Carol", "Susan Jackson", "Marshall Mathers",
            "Cauth Bodva", "Ringo Starr" };


        try {
            font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(), Configurationz.Fontz.FONT_1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_profile_friend_fragment, R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName, values) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
                        View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName);
                        tv.setTypeface(font1);
                        return rowView;
                    }

        };

      } 

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data

      }
}
```

now when I open that activity, it just loads infinitely and there is no error message?

Comment: `this doesnt work?` ellaborate it. Also print exception in try and catch don't leave it blank!

Comment: well there is no error, the font just doesnt change :( I will print the exception and show it here in a few minutes. Sorry about that

Comment: there is a nullpointerexception for the textview.

Comment: adding logcat to your question would be great!

Comment: added a screenshot of logcat in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're extending `SherlockListFragment` and you don't have a `onCreateView()` method in that fragment(at least not in the code you posted) it seems you're trying to change the font of the `TextViews` from the rows of the `ListView`(you look for a `TextView` with an id that you pass to the adapter). You're not doing this the right way, you'll need a small change to the adapter for that.

Related to the `NullPointerExceptiuon`(as a side note, **NEVER** ignore exception like you did with that empty `catch` clause), that is happening because although the `getView()` will return a valid view of the fragment(the list), the rows of the `ListView` aren't yet built, you just previously set the adapter(which doesn't make the list's rows available right away).

To change the `Typeface` of the `TextView` from the `ListView` rows try something like:

```
final Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(), Configurationz.Fontz.FONT_1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_profile_friend_fragment, R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName, values) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
                        View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName);
                        tv.setTypeface(font1);
                        return rowView;
                    }

        };
```

Comment: Im not using an onCreateView method. Should I? And if the answer is yes, which part of this code should I put there, and which part of it should remain in onActivityCreated?

Comment: @J.Kowalski You don't need to override `onCreateView` if all you want is to have a `ListView`(as a `ListFragment` already overrides `onCreateView()` to provide the `ListView`) so the answer is no. The question is if you want to change the font for the text in the rows of the `ListView`, if yes then use the code I posted in the question.

Comment: @J.Kowalski I don't see this in the new code you posted, but do you set the new adapter on the `ListView`, `setListAdapter(adapter);`?

Comment: no I dont do this. And I also dont think I have a ListView? what should I do? This is the whole code

Comment: @J.Kowalski You do have a `ListView`, you just need to set the adapter on it. In your code, after the line where you create the adapter(`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Arr....`) just add the line `setListAdapter(adapter);` in the same `onActivityCreated()` method.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, there's a `NPE` being thrown in the try-catch block:

```
tvMyFriendsListFriendName = (TextView) 
                         getView().findViewById(R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName);

try {
    font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                         getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(), 
                                     Configurationz.Fontz.FONT_1);

    tvMyFriendsListFriendName.setTypeface(font1); //this doesnt work.
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

It seems that a `TextView` with `id = tvMyFriendsListFriendName` is not defined in your fragment's layout. The View returned by `getView()` is the one you inflate in the fragment's `onCreateView(...)`. And if the layout file you used in `onCreateView(...)` does not contain `R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName`, `tvMyFriendsListFriendName` will be initialized to `null`, causing an exception on this line:

```
tvMyFriendsListFriendName.setTypeface(font1);
```

It also seems like you wish to set the typeface of the TextView in your ListView's item. To do that you can override your ArrayAdapter's `getView(...)` method and set the typeface there:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
       new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                  R.layout.my_profile_friend_fragment,
                            R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName, values) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // 'font1' is the font you get from Typeface.createFromAsset(...)
        // So, initialization of 'font1' will have to go before you define
        // the ArrayAdapter
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMyFriendsListFriendName)).setTypeface(font1);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not using an onCreateView method. Should I? And if the answer is yes, which part of this code should I put there, and which part of it should remain in onActivityCreated?

Comment: @J.Kowalski I believe user Luksprog has answered most of your questions. You might want to consider having the `onCreateView(...)` method in future because this is where you would initialize your fragment's view. For instance, if you want to make changes to your view in code (as opposed to using xml), you would make them in `onCreateView(...)` before returning the view.